# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'batch_matrix_band_part'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I tried to solve the exercise in this website 
[Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/)

the exercise is:

> The model architecture in inference() differs slightly from the
>   CIFAR-10 model specified in cuda-convnet. In particular, the top
>   layers of Alex's original model are locally connected and not fully
>   connected. Try editing the architecture to exactly reproduce the
>   locally connected architecture in the top layer.

I tried to add  `(batch_matrix_band_part)` function in the `cifar10.py` in last part of `inference()::`

```
with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [192, NUM_CLASSES],
                                      stddev=1/192.0, wd=0.0)
biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [NUM_CLASSES],
                          tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
##softmax_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local4, weights), biases, name=scope.name)  ## fully connection layer

WeightTemp = tf.batch_matrix_band_part(weights, -1, 1, name=None)  ##using band matrix to be locally connected
                                                                     ## tf.batch_matrix_band_part(input, num_lower, num_upper, name=None)
softmax_linear= tf.add(tf.matmul(local4, weightTemp), biases, name-scope.name)
tf.nn.softmax(softmax_linear, dim=-1, name=None)  ## for normalize the logits
_activation_summary(softmax_linear)
return softmax_linear
```

but this is give me this error::

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'batch_matrix_band_part'
```

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly as the error is saying - tensorflow does not have a method called `batch_matrix_band_part`. Instead, use `tf.matrix_band_part`